# Maintaining ''Items to Groups relationship" in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am using two tables for maintaining `Items-Groups` relationship.

I have `items` table which will have two columns `ItemName` and `Groups`.

The other table is `Group` which has a column `GroupName`

User will add one or more groups to each item.  The user will then query for no of items assigned to that group.

Currently I am appending the `GroupName` to `Groups` column and while querying for no of groups I use `%Groups%` in where query.

But if the user adds the same group twice, I need to check and remove.

Is there any better way to maintain these relationships?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't try to store multiple items in a single column(*).

Instead, create 3 tables - `Items`, `Groups` and `ItemGroups`. `ItemGroups` will store 1 row for each group that an item belongs to, e.g.:

```
CREATE TABLE ItemGroups (
     ItemID int not null,
     GroupID int not null,
     constraint FK_ItemGroups_Items FOREIGN KEY (ItemID) references Items (ItemID),
     constraint FK_ItemGroups_Groups FOREIGN KEY (GroupID) references Groups (GroupID),
     constraint PK_ItemGroups PRIMARY KEY (ItemID,GroupID)
)
```

Note that, by adding the primary key on `ItemID,GroupID`, we've prevented duplicates from occurring, with no further work.

---

(*) SQL has one data structure designed for containing multiple items. It doesn't have arrays, lists, dictionaries, etc. It just has one structure. And it's called a table. Things work well if you *use* this structure. Things don't work nearly so well if you try to fake some other kind of structure using e.g. string values stored in a single column.

Answer (score 1):

Having a concatenated field of groups prevents automated database integrity enforcing and disallows indexing, thus certain queries will be very slow.

Add (or change) primary key ItemId to Items and have a foreign key ItemId in Group. Then you can do `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Group WHERE ItemId = X` to get the number of groups assigned to an item.

The above assumes a one-to-many relationship of items to group, **if it's a many-to-many relationship:**

Instead of the foreign key in Group, have another table `ItemGroupMapping(ItemId FK, GroupId FK)`.

Also adding primary key GroupId to Group might be a good idea i.t.o good database design.